# Can you remove dashes from margin and padding classes in tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

While using [tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/), is it possible to remove the dashes from [margins](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin) and [padding](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding) selectors?

For example:

`.mb-1`  would be `.mb1`

`.-mx-1` would be `.mxn1`

I personally think this looks cleaner and wanted to know if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through plugins, but requires a lot of extra work. Pulling from these two ([one](https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues/102), [two](https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues/523)) github threads, here is an example of a plugin that removes the dash from the `mb-#` class, ie: `.mb-1` will become `.mb1`:

```
import _ from 'lodash'

export default function(variants) {
  return function ({ addUtilities, config }) {
    const utilities = _.map(config('margin'), (value, modifier) => {
      return defineClass(`mb${modifier}`, {
        'margin-bottom': `${value}`,
      })
    })

    addUtilities(utilities, variants)
  }
}
```

Essentially the plugin is creating its own custom classes for the margin bottom class. It would take a lot of work to do this for each module but, again, it is possible. ps: the above plugin requires you to disable the default tailwind margin in your `tailwind.config.js` file.

```
module:
  modules: {
    // ...
-   margin: [...],
+   margin: false,
    // ...
  }
```